# Definite integral with parameters and absolute value function

Tags: definite-integrals, absolute-value

I'm trying to find out which integration trick is going to help me with this integral:
$$
\int_{t}^{\infty} \exp(- |x - a|) \mathrm{\ d}x
$$
where $t, a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Solving an *indefinite* integral with the absolute value is easy, just splitting into two parts and solve the sum $\int_{-\infty}^{a}\ldots + \int_{a}^{\infty}\ldots$

But I'm afraid that the parameter $t$ makes things more complicated (such as having two solutions, depending on whether $t < a$ or not). Or is there any substitution or another trick?

Comment: Your two parts are actually each definite integrals. [improper, but still definite.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make a substitution of $x-a=u$ to get that the integral is: $$\int_{t-a}^\infty e^{-|u|}du$$If $t-a$ is greater than $0$ then integrate $e^{-u}$ like a regular integral. But if $t-a<0$ then calculate the following: $$\int^{0}_{t-a}e^{-u}du+\int_{t-a}^\infty e^{-u}du$$The logic behind these conditions is the fact that there is a line of symmetry at $u=a$.

Comment: Thanks, so a substitution works, quite straightforward in the hindsight. I'm wondering if there's any "one-liner" (without having to branch on $t - a <> 0$

Comment: @JohnDoe You're welcome! I don't think we could make a "one-liner" because of the absolute value function. It makes the function not continuous.